# Electrical Panel Specifications

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

My electrical panel, located on the side of my house with underground supply, has these 2 statements in the description on the inside door:

"MAINS 125 AMP MAX" and "MAX BRANCH BREAKER 100 AMP"

So what's the capacity of the panel 100 or 125? If it's currently limited to 100 could it be modified to 125 amps without replacing the whole panel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your panel is allowed up to a 125A *Main Breaker*.

Only the *branch circuit breakers* are limited to 100A.

That means the panel busing has a rating of at least 125A.

120% of that is 150A.

Thus, the solar rule says that if most of your house's breakers are in this panel and located between the main and solar breaker, then the main + solar breaker may add up to 150A.

Comment: "Harper jumps to the solar conclusion!" _is probably right_ ;)